# Powerpoint to Image conversion using c# without interop

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

Simple and direct question.

Powerpoint to Image (JPEG, PNG,...)  conversion using c# **without** interop, does anyone has done it?

Without Interop, for using in a server environment for automating processes?

(Desktop applications do not count)

Answer (score 0):

Use NPOI to read ppt files.
However, currently only supports ppt but not pptx

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Slides for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component.aspx) should do the trick.